# What is the SomeClass::class.'@someMethod' syntax pattern in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I have never seen this before in PHP and have zero clue how to search for this. I was pulling up some Java examples, and that really doesn't help.

Specifically, I saw this in Laravel's Spark in the `scriptVariables()` method within the main Spark object. I have an idea of what this is doing, but what's the difference between this and simply writing: `SomeClass::someMethod()`?

And please show me the correct place in the manual, if that exists. Just point me in the right direction.

Comment: These are static methods. They are called without creating object. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: I can't even tell what syntax exactly you mean. Please give an example inline formatted as code.

Comment: The most obvious difference is that `SomeClass::someMethod()` is a static call to a method, and `SomeClass::class.'@someMethod'` is just a string that does not call anything. However, I imagine the latter is used as a representation of a method to call - it will be string-parsed by Laravel and run using Laravel's internal code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual difference between `::class` and a static call `::someMethod()` is that `::class` on any object will return the FQCN of a class (fully qualified class name). Take the following example class:

```
namespace Macondo\Buendia\Admin;

class User {}
```

Running the following;

```
echo Macondo\Buendia\Admin\User::class;
```

or

```
use Macondo\Buendia\Admin\User;
echo User::class;
```

Will both return:

```
Macondo\Buendia\Admin\User
```

This makes it pretty easier, for instance in route declarations of Laravel to create a decent, persistent way of defining the controller actions:

```
Route::get('/', App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class . '@home');
Route::get('/dashboard', App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class . '@dashboard');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#controllers-and-namespaces

---

To clarify, the `SomeController::class . '@someMethod'` is **not** a static call. Laravel will resolve the specific controller and method using "the Container" (also called inversion of control/ioc).